# How to attach events to new added html elements

Tags: javascript, html

If I had a function like this:

```
document.someElement.click = function(){alert(555);}
```

and I don't have in the element `someElement` in the HTML page itself, so after I add `someElement` to the page, but the code before doesn't work.

What is the best way to add event listeners to (new) dynamically added HTML elements?

Comment: Were you looking for [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) or something?

Comment: You have to bind it once you added/created the element or use event delegation (assuming the element has some property that makes it identifiable). A great source to learn all kinds of stuff about event handling is http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 4):

There are two common strategies here.

1. Hook the event on the element after you add the element to the DOM.
2. Use *event delegation*.

The first is fairly straightforward, so I'll focus on the second:

The idea with event delegation is that most DOM events "bubble" from the element where they occur up to the document, and you can handle them at any level.

So for instance, suppose you have

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

You can hook the `click` event on the container div, and then if you do something like this:

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = "Hi there";
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(span);
```

...then, when you click the `span`, the event will bubble up to the container, and you see the click in the container's `click` handler.

You can tell which element started the event by using the `target` property on the `event` object.

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<button id="theButton">Click To Add</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Note that this code is at the end of the document
(function() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  // Hook clicks on the button
  document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = buttonClick;

  // Hook clicks on the container
  container.onclick = containerClick;

  // Handle button clicks
  function buttonClick() {
    var child = document.createElement('div');
    child.id = ('d' + container.childNodes.length) +
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    child.innerHTML = "I'm child div '" + child.id + "'";
    container.appendChild(child);
  }

  // Handle container clicks
  function containerClick(event) {
    event = event || window.event;

    alert("You clicked child '" + event.target.id + "'");
  }

})();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/icofar/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/icofar/1/edit)

Note: I've used `onclick` to keep things simple. In production, I recommend using `addEventListener` (or `attachEvent` on IE). In fact, I typically recommend using a good library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) for the significant utility functionality they provide (including smoothing over the `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` thing).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) ([`attachEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE) to register a click handler on a newly created element, for example:

```
var x = document.createElement('div');
x.innerText = 'click me';

x.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('i am clicked');
});

document.body.appendChild(x);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/uhomey/2/)

**Update**

Do take a look at [TJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14001143/1338292); he's basically saying that you can set up a container onto which you define a click handler; any elements that are added inside will have their events bubble up to the container. This way you only need one click handler and not one per element.